# Python for loop not looping through all the elements

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to code my first `webscraper` using `python` and `BeautifulSoup`.

I'm trying to retrieve all the URLs for all the listings on a webpage but instead of getting an array with all the URLs I only get one URL.

Following is the code I used

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pararius.com/apartments/enschede'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

compartments = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"property-list-item-container"})

#Here is where im trying to store all the urls in url_det 
for compartment in compartments:
    url_det = compartment.h2.a["href"]
```

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop will overwrite the content of `url_det`, use instead a list comprehension to store all the values in a list, for example:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.pararius.com/apartments/enschede'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

compartments = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"property-list-item-container"})

url_det = [compartment.h2.a["href"] for compartment in compartments]

print(url_det)
>>> ['/house-for-rent/enschede/PR0001596564/otto-van-taverenstraat', ... , '/house-for-rent/enschede/PR0001594320/hanenberglanden']
```